# Calculate $\int\limits_{0}^{1}{f\left( x \right)dx}$ when $f$ satisfies three given conditions.

Tags: real-analysis, definite-integrals

> Let $f$ be a function with $f'$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ such that $$f\left( 1 \right)=0,\quad\int\limits_{0}^{1}{{{\left[ f'(x) \right]}^{2}}dx=7},\quad\int\limits_{0}^{1}{{{x}^{2}}f\left( x \right)dx=\frac{1}{3}.}$$
>   Calculate $\displaystyle\int\limits_{0}^{1}{f\left( x \right)dx}$.

Comment: I have not determined how to solve it.

Comment: @Mary Integration by parts seems relevant here

Comment: I would integrate $x^2f(x)$ by parts and see what happens.  I haven't actually tried it though.

Comment: D you mean $f'$ is continuous on $(0,1)$?

Comment: I did the same but did not give the answer!

Comment: $\int_0^1 x^2 f(x)dx+\int_0^1 \frac{x^3}{3} f'(x)dx=0$ By fundamental theorem of Calculus. I am trying to do more...

Answer (score 7):

Hint. Note that by [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality)
$$
\begin{align*}\frac{1}{3}=\int_0^1 x^2 f(x)dx&=\left[\frac{x^3}{3} f(x)\right]_0^1-\int_0^1\frac{x^3}{3}\, f'(x)dx=\frac{1}{3}\int_0^1 (-x^3) f'(x)dx\\
&\leq  \frac{1}{3}\left(\int_{0}^{1}x^6 dx\right)^{1/2} \left(\int_{0}^{1} (f'(x))^2dx\right)^{1/2}=\frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{7}}\cdot \sqrt{7}= \frac{1}{3}.\end{align*}$$
Now recall that in the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, the equality holds if and only if one function is a scalar multiple of the other.

P.S. "Without" the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: from the first line $\int_0^1 x^3 f'(x)dx=-1$ and therefore
$$\int_0^1(7x^3+ f'(x))^2 dx=7^2\int_0^1 x^6 dx+2\cdot 7\int_0^1 x^3 f'(x) dx +\int_0^1(f'(x))^2 dx=0$$
which implies that the non-negative continuous function $(7x^3+ f'(x))^2$ is zero, that is $f'(x)=-7x^3$. Hence
$$f(x)=f(1)+\int_1^x f'(t)dt=0-\frac{7}{4}[t^4]_1^x=\frac{7(1-x^4)}{4}.$$

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand how Cauchy-Schwarz inequality applicable on definite integral. Isn't it just about discrete math?

Comment: No, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#L2

Comment: Are there any other answers that do not use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality?

Comment: @Mary This is a problem made for Cauchy-Schwarz. If you want to avoid it you can mimic the steps in the derivation of CS to get one: consider $\int_0^1(f'(x) + 7x^3)^2\,{\rm d}x$. Show that this has to evaluate to $0$ and deduce $f(x)$ from this (integrand is stricktly positive).

Comment: @Mary See my P.S.